# BFS algorithm returns segmentation fault

Tags: c, graph, breadth-first-search

I tried to write a BFS algorithm, where nod is the first node, viz is a vector with the elements 0 as not visited and 1 as visited, a is the adjency matrix, n is the number of nodes, q is the queue. However, from whatever reason that i do not understand, the code is not working. Do you have any idea why? I would be thankful.
THis is my code:

```
   void BFS(int nod, int viz[], int a[100][100], int n, int q[], int *f, int *r )
{

    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if(a[nod][i] && !viz[i])
        {
            (*r)++;
            q[(*r)] = i;
        }}
        if((*f) <= (*r))
        {    f++;
            viz[q[(*f)]] = 1;
            printf("Am vizitat nodul %d \n", *f);
            BFS(q[(*f)],viz,a,n,q,&f,&r);
        }
    }
```

And i called it in main like this:

```
BFS(nod1,viz,a,n,q,&f,&r);
```

Comment: Arrays are indexed from `0`

Comment: I do not have a node 0, that is why the array starts at 1

Comment: When you recurse, you pass pointers to some of the pointers you received instead of forwarding the pointers themselves.  This is certainly wrong, and your compiler ought to at least be warning you.